# Azure Table Storage Timestamp monotonically increasing across entities and partitions?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

Azure Table Storage Timestamp property is a monotonic increasing value inside the scope of a single entity.

Do anyone know if this is also the case for partitions and the whole table or even storage account?

I need to do incremental loading from a Storage Table and use Timestamp to detect if a entity has been changed since last load.

My worry is that from the time i start reading a partition a new update might arrive that i miss but get an update on a yet to be read partition.

This means if i do a `var latestTimestamp = entities.Max(x => x.Timestamp)` i might overshoot the timestamp and miss updates.

Imagin the following:

1. Update to entity1
2. Update to entity2
3. Incremental read begin
4. Read entity 1
5. Update to entity 1 <- Latest at point in time but not read
6. Read entity 2
7. Update to entity 3 <- Latest at point in time and read
8. Read entity 3
9. Incremental read finished
10. Max(Timestamp) == Entity3.Timestamp

Starting next incremental read form Entity3's timestamp will cause me to miss the updated entity1.

Do anyone have any insights into this?

My solution otherwise would be to overlap the timestamps a little and allow idempotent updates to the target system.

Comment: It’s not really clear what problem you’re trying to solve. Can you elaborate on that. In any case, querying on Timestamp is a bad idea as it leads to full table scan.

Comment: @GauravMantri My  problem is im afraid that i miss out on the updated Entity1 but set latest timestamp from Entity3 for my next incremenetal load, thereby excluding the update to entity1 as it is later.